# How to change ArrayList value

Tags: c#

I want to remove all '\0' characters from the items of an ArrayList in c#. Here is my code:

```
ArrayList users = um.getAllUsers(server,Instance); //user count=3
```

So now I want to add a code in order to replase all '\0' with empty string in all the items of the list.

Is this possible?

Comment: What type is a user? A string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it's a little odd to still be using `ArrayList` in 2010... and also to have Camel cased names (`getAllUsers` rather than `GetAllUsers`) but still...

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
{
    string user = (string) users[i];
    user = user.Replace("\0", "");
    users[i] = user;
}
```

Comment: It properly don't matter in this case, but I would use if (user == "\0") user = string.Empty instead of a .Replace because it not only replaces if the string is = "\0".

Comment: @lasseespeholt: It's not clear what the question actually means - whether it's meant to only replace "\0" for a whole item, or within each item.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not stuck with some ancient version of .NET, you might be interested in upgrading your code to use the generic [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) collection and have a look at LINQ:

```
List<string> users = um.getAllUsers(server,Instance)
                       .Cast<string>()
                       .Select(user => user.Replace("\0", ""))
                       .ToList();
```

(I assume `getAllUsers` returns an ArrayList containing `string` instances).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, simply call the replace method like that :

```
ArrayList users = um.getAllUsers(server,Instance);

for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
{
    users[i] = ((String) users[i]).Replace ("\0", "");
}
```

But I would suggest to use List instead of ArrayList if you can. Generics are good for you :-)

Comment: (Commenting one of you answers because I can't private message you): 
You suggested an edit on one of my answers that got rejected before I could accept it. (About using MemoryStream.ToArray() rather than MemoryStream.GetBuffer()).
You're suggestion was correct, and I have manually changed my answer to follow your advice. Thanks.